# Connect from ios device to localhost

Tags: ios, http, flutter, localhost, device

I have a REST service running on my host. I can perform an HTTP request to this service from my flutter app when running on the iOS simulator using the code below:

```dart
final response = await http.get('http://localhost:8085/my/service');
```

However, it fails when I'm running the app on my iOS device. My device is connected via USB.

```sh
Runner[574:66922] flutter: Error SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 61, address = localhost, port = 49575
```

What do I need to configure to connect to localhost from my iOS device?

I've already disabled in iTunes -> Summary "Sync with this iPad over Wi-Fi".

Comment: When you are running on the device `localhost` is the device. That's what "local host" means. It is 127.0.0.1, the loopback IP address. It only works on the simulator because the simulator is running on the same device as your app (ie. your Mac)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of **localhost** you can use your current ip

to get it In the command window type: ipconfig

> Note that you must be on the same network

Comment: Isn't it possible to connect directly to localhost being connected by USB (without enabling wifi connection)?

Comment: i dont think so, but you can upload your service on hosting domin for testing without need to write the ip every time.

Comment: My god! You are absolutely right! And I was hitting my head against the wall why it was not working on localhost. :facepalm: